# Display form data in same html page

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Hi i am new to html programming and i am facing a small problem.
I have designed a HTML form and there are few fields viz. Name,age etc.
I am filling them and there is a SAVE button below. Clicking that button will display the entered fields in a separate div in the same html page after form validation.
I need some help. am having problem in multiple validation as well as Displaying the items in the div.

```
<html>
<body>
<form onsubmit="validation();">
    <table border="2">
        <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fn" id="firstname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="ln" id="lastname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Father's First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="ffn" id="ffirstname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Father's Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fln" id="flastname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Age:</td><td><input type="text" name="ag" id="age"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Gender:
                <select name="gend">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
        </td>   
        <td>Address:<textarea rows=4 cols=10 name="add" id="addr"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Pincode:</td><td><input type="text" name="pc" id="pincode" maxlength="6"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="pn" id="phonenumber" maxlength="10"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Mobile Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="mb" id="mobilenumber" maxlength="10"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" value="Save"></center></td></tr>
    </table>
    <script>
            function validation()
            {
                var x=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
                var y=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
                var z=document.getElementById("ffirstname").value;
                var v=document.getElementById("flastname").value;
                var a=document.getElementById("age").value;
                var alpha=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
                var valid=true;

                if(!x.match(alpha))
                {
                    alert("Alphabets only!");
                    valid=false;
                }
                if(!y.match(alpha))
                {
                    alert("Alphabets only!");
                    valid=false;
                }
                if(!z.match(alpha))
                {
                    alert("Alphabets only!");
                    valid=false;
                }
                if(!v.match(alpha))
                {
                    alert("Alphabets only!");
                    valid=false;
                }
                if(a<18 || a>30)
                {
                    alert("Age should be between 18-30");
                    valid=false;
                }


            }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you had a specific question.  "having problem" doesn't tell me where you need assistance.

Comment: What he said ^^  Really, all you're missing is some getElementById JavaScript to populate you form fields in your divs.

Comment: how to display the data entered in the form in a separate **div** in the same page?

Comment: @durbnpoisn didnt get you. Can you elaborate a bit to me?

Comment: @BiswarupDass: Where is the `div`?  You can identify an element by `id` (like you already do) and set its `innerHtml` property to any value, for example.

Comment: i have not wrote anything yet in the div. Can you give me an example @David

Comment: @BiswarupDass: `document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHtml = "Some value";`

Comment: i should write this inside the div block?

Answer (score 0):

For validation it will be easier and better to use HTML5 form attributes `pattern` and `required`.
For reference, see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp
And I don't see any code used for displaying data in a div! You first need to post the code in order to get any help for it.

Comment: that is the problem. I need help in how to display the data in the div

Comment: Use this example:
**HTML**:
`<div id="fn"></div>`

**JavaScript**:
`document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML=document.getElementById("firstname").value`